# Azure app run function locally

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I have a function in an Azure app that I want to be able to call from programs that are only running locally. Is there a way to do this? If so, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you start from one of our **HttpTrigger templates**, you'll have an Http endpoint that you can invoke securely from whatever client you choose. The Functions Portal will give you the **Function Url** that you can use. E.g. the Url will look something like:

https://myfunctions.azurewebsites.net/api/Test?code=abc123

Get your Function Url from the portal and plug it into whatever client you have, being sure to manage the code value securely of course.